# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' when running code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm really confused. I am using Visual Studio Code to work on some assignments for school. I am running them in the anaconda prompt. I have one assignment where I have to use numpy and one that I need to use pandas for. I keep getting the module not found error when i try to import these. I tried to run pip install numpy in my navigation path and it said "Requirement already satisfied: numpy in (navigational path). I think I get that i can't run these because they're already installed but then i run into an error when i try to do things like run "np.random.seed(56)", it says 'np' is not defined or 'pd' is not defined or 'DataFrame' is not defined. I guess i'm just confused about it being installed but not installed ?? Please help. Also for reference I've tried to change the python interpreter to [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUQ8E.png) and none of them work

Comment: Anaconda has it's own package manager outside of `pip`. Try `conda install numpy`

Comment: should i put this at the beginning where i would normally do import numpy as np?

Comment: You should run that in your terminal, the same way you ran `pip`

Comment: I ran it and it says that numpy already is there (requirement already satisified) but i still can't get my code to run. I am trying to build this in visual studio and i have a data frame and the np.random.seed() function and if i remove the "import numpy as np", they dont work but if i leave the import numpy as np in the .py file in vs it says module not found

Answer (score 0):

You have not selected the proper environment. Could you check where you have installed your package through `pip --version` `or pip show numpy`? In the picture, you are using the WindowsApps python interpter.